# FileNotFoundException for hive/lib/hive-builtins-0.9.0.jar in Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hdfs, cloudera

I've a configured Hadoop 0.23 on my local box and got it work with a simple map-reduce wordcount program. I Have configured Hive to work with it. All the DDL queries works fine. But when i fire queries that have aggregates (which will trigger Map-educe jobs)

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /Users/varadham/projects/hadoop/hive/lib/hive-builtins-0.9.0.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:738)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:604)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.main(ExecDriver.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File does not exist: /Users/varadham/projects/hadoop/hive/lib/hive-builtins-0.9.0.jar)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the same file /Users/varadham/projects/hadoop/hive/lib/hive-builtins-0.9.0.jar in your hadoop file system. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the jar in HDFS.